# Twitter API timeline information for iOS 5

Tags: ios, api, uitableview, ios5, twitter

Right now I am making a twitter app for iOS 5, and I need help with the `TWRequest` class. I Cant figure out anywhere on the web how to get the users timeline and put it a tableview. All of the tutorials and other websites only show how to post things to twitter. How can do an autenticated request to twitter and then put that timeline in a tableview?? Any help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Virindh Borra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second example at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/making-api-requests-twrequest shows how to make authenticated requests for a user's timeline. The results are parsed into a standard NSArray that should be fairly easy to work with and put into a UITableView.